# Auto Speech Recognizer with pre trained dataset

Tags: speech

I want to have an Auto Speech Recognizer with the trained platform i.e. voice mods.
 for eg:-
i have two words very similar in saying so the system must listen to the compplete word and in any dilax and verify it and give the output.

How to do it.

I have searched but i'm completely blank on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Which technology do you want to use? There are different frameworks available out there, e.g. the Dragonfly framework (https://code.google.com/p/dragonfly) or the System.Speech.Recognition namespace for .net projects. For mobile devices you could take a closer look at the speech recognition API offered by Google.

Comment: i want it for mobile devices and i have implemented the voice recognizer in adnroid but now i want to define my own libraries + i want like people pronounce words in different way so i want to reconize that and gives output

Comment: I got  PocketSpinx but i dont knw android ndk is being used and all..!1

Answer (score 0):

In this point of view, fine tuning with Android speech recognition API is not possible.
you may need to start from the scratch to do this..

if you want to keep using google speech recognition API, then you need to do post processing... this called NLU (Natural Language Understanding) or NLP (Natural Language Processing).

simple concept is whatever STT (speech to text) result came from google API, you need to grouping them into one final output. what so ever your different accent or intonation to be one. or this process has value when it needs some contents to understand and do some action like what is the weather in Seoul?

Going back to your question, fine tuning for differentiating similar pronunciation words needs to have AM (Acoustic Model) and LM (Language Model) which was trained that kinds of words set accordingly. So you need to train the model from the scratch or using exist model with acoustic model adaptation will also works.

for good start point with opensource is HTK or Sphinx. If you have budget to buy, then AT&T's watson is the best tools for speech recognition area so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a different approach, that is simpler than trying to get Sphinx to work.

Use a phonetic matching algorithm like soundEx to find if the user is more likely to have said one word or the other. I would modify the soundEx algorithm to make it easier to match strings. If your words of different enough it should do a good job.

[Here is some code to do it](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text/match/SoundsLikeThresholdWordMatcher.java)